# Kotlin files not able to use R.java

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, build.gradle, kotlin-interop

I created a new layout file in the appropriate resource folder. After syncing, when I try to reference the layout file, i.e. R.layout.activity_test, R is an "unresolved symbol". When I try to build in AS it fails.

The interesting thing is that if I manually import the R file and use it in code, when I try to build on command line, it works. The other thing is when I try to access the layout file using R in a Java file, that also works. So I know R.java is being generated.

I tried creating a totally new project, and R is accessible in Kotlin files.

What is the problem here?

Things I have tried:

- Cleaned then built
- Invalidated Caches / Restart
- Blow away .gradle folders and recreate indexes

Other info:

- AS v3.0.1
- Tried both Kotlin v1.1.2-4 and v1.1.60
- Gradle v4.2.1
- Gradle Plugin v3.0.0

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find any solution?

Comment: how did you solved your issue I am seeing the same issue in a legacy project that is starting to migrate slowly to kotlin

Answer (score 1):

**Invalidate Caches/Restart worked for me.**

```
Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version. These files were found in the classpath:
C:/Users/R3ZA/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/me.eugeniomarletti.kotlin.metadata/kotlin-compiler-lite/1.0.3-k-1.2.40/a16e967c276379eaf6e1fa03af77664f003db947/kotlin-compiler-lite-1.0.3-k-1.2.40.jar (version 1.2)
C:/Users/R3ZA/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.3.20/eb2a232734e09fcd1b958a5c7520a93c6de38b32/kotlin-stdlib-1.3.20.jar (version 1.3)
C:/Users/R3ZA/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.3.20/7d7934e26ce34da1a0a8d00e38038d7cf3375e89/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.3.20.jar (version 1.3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following under *android* section in your application module:

```
android {
  ...
  sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
  }
}
```

> This lets Android Studio know that the kotlin directory is a source
>   root, so when the project model is loaded into the IDE it will be
>   properly recognized. Alternatively, you can put Kotlin classes in the
>   Java source directory, typically located in `src/main/java`.

---

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#android-studio

Answer (score 0):

If you have a warning in your project please fix it.
in my case my Gradle version had a version Compile warning.
the App runs fine but the R class was not recognized, so I change the gradle version and fix the warnings and all works well.